# Small jquery bug in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

If you go to this site http://rochesterwaterskishow.com/staging, hover over the `about` link in FF or Chrome and you can see that a menu popsup. When you do the same thing in IE8, the menu does not show. I have not checked IE7.

What is causing the menu not to show in IE8?

jQuery:

```
    $('#flyout').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('div').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('div').hide();
    });
```

Comment: The slider effect is cool (I wouldn't use it though)

Comment: try changing it to `$("#flyout").delegate("*", "hover", f, g);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, the bug is not in the menu or your jQuery expression at all. It's in a line above:

```
<h1><a href="http://rochesterwaterskishow.com/staging/index.php/site/index"><img src="http://rochesterwaterskishow.com/staging/assets/images/RWSStandardLogo.gif" class="logo" /></h1>
```

There's no closing `</a>` here, which makes IE throw a wobbly. Fix that up and you should be good to go.

Comment: Good catch. I guess i just needed to look up a few lines. Thanks.

Comment: The only way I noticed it was by opening in IE8 and manually removing the CSS rule for `display:none`. When that worked fine, I knew the issue had to be related to DOM parsing, and read backwards until I found something invalid. If manually removing the CSS rule hadn't've worked, I would have known the issue was in your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$(this).children('div')` isn't working in IE8.  I don't know why (edit: I guess it's because of the unclosed `<a>` tag mentioned in Interrobang's post).

I did find that this should work:

```
$('#flyout').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div').hide();
});
```

The code, in general would be more robust against these types of issues if you put a class in the div tag that you want to hide/show and then you'd have more robust ways to find it rather than relying on there being one and only one div tag in exactly the right place..

Comment: Why the downvote?  My observations are all true.  OK, so I didn't see the unclosed <a> tag earlier that seems to have confused the DOM, but why downvote for a work-around and a bunch of IE8 debugging to figure out which piece of jQuery wasn't doing what was intended.  Seems a little harsh.  Certainly isn't much of an incentive to go spend 15 minutes doing IE8 debugging.